# Настойка Ant в Eclipse.

Tags: ant, eclipse, java

Здравствуйте.
Запускаю build.xml, но компилятор выдаёт ошибки. (При этом, без участия Ant проект компилируется и работает нормально.) Одна из ошибок, как пример, - "type javax.swing.JComboBox does not take parameters". Убираю параметр - ошибка исчезает, но IDE выдаёт предупреждение, что класс параметризован (и он таки параметризован). Видимо, Ant и Eclipse пользуются разными версиями стандартных библиотек. Но вот не могу понять, куда за ними обращается среда. В Installed JREs есть 2 пути, и при использовании любого из указанных там появляется сообщение об ошибке. Собственно, вопрос в том, куда смотрит IDE и как туда навести Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run -> External tools -> External tools configuration... -> [конфигурация вашего Ant Builder'а] -> JRE

Указываете ту же JRE, что и в проекте.

Answer (score 1):

В eclipse classpath задан в настройках project'а. в случае ant он задается в самом скрипте (build.xml). Не удивительно что в 2х случаях работает по разному (ведь в eclipse вы спокойно могли поменять его одним кликом).

Для начала можете посмотреть classpath в настройках проэкта. Если не помогло можно сделать так:

`File -> New -> Project -> Java project from existing ant build file`,

указываете ваш `build.xml`. Eclipse создаст еще один project в нем вы увидите свой код так как его видит ant (насколько это возможно).